I've run into an error in my code and I am a bit stuck
I've been developing software and have ran into an issue with it.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

void fileOP(std::ifstream testdata, std::string line, std::string csvitem, int linenumsought, int linenum);

int main(){
    std::ifstream testdata; testdata.open("testdata.txt");
    std::string line, csvitem;
    int linenum = 0;
    int linenumsought;
    std::string address;

    std::cout << "Please enter address: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, address);

    fileOP(testdata, line, csvitem, linenum, linenumsought, address);

    return 0;
}

void fileOP(std::ifstream testdata, std::string line, std::string csvitem, int linenumsought, int linenum) {

    if (testdata.is_open()) {
        while (std::getline(testdata, line)) {
            linenum++;

            if (linenum == linenumsought) {

                std::cout << line << '\n';
                std::istringstream myline(line);

                while(getline(myline, csvitem, ',')) {
                        std::cout << csvitem << '\n';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Its saying "Function cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function" referring to the testdata and address variable in fileOP(testdata, line, csvitem, linenum, linenumsought, address);
I am a bit confused about what the error is and how to fix it.

When asking questions about build errors, then please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build-log from the shown code into your question. And add a comment on the line in the shown code where you get the errors. Please [edit] your question to improve it.

With that said, for this case the problem is quite easy to guess: Stream objects can't be copied, and therefore you can't pass them as arguments by value. You need to pass references. Something I also recommend for your strings (especially if your function is supposed to modify them).

On a different note, I recommend you get the habit to not pass concrete streams to function. If you want to pass an input stream, use the generic std::istream instead. That way it doesn't matter where the stream comes from. If could be a file, or a string stream, or even std::cin.

Also on a different note, and regarding your function arguments: Besides the testdata argument, why do you pass the other arguments? They seem like they should be local variables defined inside the function itself. All in all, it seems you might need to refresh some of the early chapters of your beginners book or tutorial. And learn C++ better before attempting to create a program to be used in a commercial setting.

@Someprogrammerdude Hey! Thanks it got rid of the error and my code runs now atleast lol. There seems to be another issue now tho. Now the program wont actually display what is in the .txt file, could there be a reason with that?

Thats probably because linenumsought is not defined before you pass it into the function so the if statement is never executed.

@Genpfault Why did you replace a detailed title with something so generic?
